# std::set::equal_range for a container of std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find all the ranges [a,b] enclosing int values i, where a <= i <= b. I'm using `set<std:pair<int,int>>` for the set of ranges.

In the following, using equal range on a `vector<int>` yields the start and one past the end of the range.

When I do the same for a `set<pair<int,int>>`, the result starts and ends at one past the end of the range and therefore doesn't include the range enclosing the value.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    set<int> s1(begin(ia),end(ia));
    auto range1 = s1.equal_range(5);

    cout << *range1.first << " " << *range1.second << endl; //prints 5 6

    pair<int,int> p[] = {make_pair(1,10), 
                         make_pair(11,20),  
                         make_pair(21,30), 
                         make_pair(31,40)}; 
    set<pair<int,int>> s(begin(p), end(p));    

    auto range = s.equal_range(make_pair(12,12));

    cout << range.first->first << " " << range.first->second << endl; //prints 21 30, why?
    cout << range.second->first << " " << range.second->second << endl; //prints 21 30

}
```

`prints`
 `5 6`
`21 30`
`21 30`
Why does equal_range on the `set<pair<int,int>>` not include the range that encloses the value (12), namely [11.20]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range) is behaving completely correctly:

```
assert( std::make_pair(11, 20) < std::make_pair(12, 12) );
assert( std::make_pair(12, 12) < std::make_pair(21, 30) );
```

[11,20] is not a range, it's a pair.  The pair [12,12] is not "within" another pair, that makes no sense to even say.

[12,12] is not "within" [11,20], it's greater than it.  The less-than operator for `std::pair` compares the first elements first, and only if they're equal does it look at the second elements, so `make_pair(11,x)` is less than `make_pair(12, y)` **for any `x` and `y`**

So `equal_range` tells you that [12,12] would be inserted after [11,20] and before [21,30], which is correct.

If you want to treat pairs as ranges of values you need to write code to do that, not assume the built-in comparisons for pairs does that.  You're actually trying to find an int 12 in a range of pairs of ints, but have written code to find a pair [12,12] in a range of pairs of ints. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It does not include `[11, 20]` in the range, because it doesn't include *anything* in the range. There are no equal elements to `[12, 12]`, so it returns an empty range (represented by the half-open interval `[x, x)`).

BTW dereferencing the upper bound of the range may invoke undefined behavior, since that may be equal to `s.end()`.

Comment: Shouldn't equal range use the same `less<pair<int,int>>` default comparator as used to define the the set? In this case, the range including the 12 returns `true` because [11,20] < [12,12]

Comment: I want to find all ranges in a large set that enclose a value. Instead of using the set member, I could use find_if algorithm with a lambda that tests for enclosure but doesn't that mean I need to test all elements in the set (numbering in the millions)?

Comment: Is it possible to find all ranges with O(log(n)) by using a set member function instead?

Comment: @user1626720: If your intervals overlap (and there may be more than one covering a particular point) you want an interval tree, not `std::set`. In case the intervals don't overlap (as is the case in your example), what you do is almost right. You just look immediately below and at the lower bound.

Comment: Thanks @jpalecek: The example wasn't brilliant as the intervals do overlap (and duplicate). The reason for using a `std::set` is I'm hoping to use the stdlib red-black tree implementation rather than roll my own interval tree. Am I barking up the wrong tree? :P

Answer (score 1):

The pair `[12, 12]` is sorted after `[11, 20]` and before `[21, 30]`.

[std::set::equal_range()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/equal_range/) includes a range of *equal* elements. There is no equal element in your set (especially not `[11, 20]`), so `equal_range()` returns `[21, 30], [21, 30]`.

Answer (score 1):

`equal_range` is implemented as to call lower_bound first then call upper_bound to search the rest data set.

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  pair<ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator>
    equal_range ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value )
{
  ForwardIterator it = lower_bound (first,last,value);
  return make_pair ( it, upper_bound(it,last,value) );
}
```

Look at your sample:
It calls `lower_bound` to locate the lower bound of value(which is pair(12,12), which arrives at

```
pair<int,int> p[] = {make_pair(1,10), 
                     make_pair(11,20), 
                     make_pair(21,30),   // <--- lower_bound() points to here
                     make_pair(31,40)};
```

Then it calls upper_bound() to search on (21,30),(31,40) and it cound't find it, it returns (21,30)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `std::set<std::pair<int, int> >` won't help you much in intersecting it with your integer: You can find the `s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(i + 1, i + 1)` to cut off the search but all ranges starting at an index lower than `i + 1` can potentially include the value `i` if the second boundary is large enough. What might help is if you know the maximum size of the ranges in which case you can bound the search towards the front by `s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(i - max_range_size, i - max_range_size))`. You'll need to inspect each of the ranges in turn to identify if your `i` falls into them:

```
auto it    = s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(i - max_range_size, i - max_range_size));
auto upper = s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(i + 1, i + 1));
for (; it != upper; ++it) {
    if (i < it->second) {
        std::cout << "range includes " << i << ": "
                  << [" << it.first << ", " << it->second << "]\n";
}
```

(or something like this...)

Comment: These ranges can overlap so even if I know the maximum range by checking first this won't lead to an improvement over O(n). For example if ranges are like `[a [c [e... ...f] d] b]` and `e < i < f`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you want something better than O(n) you need a different algorithm, e.g., using [range trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).